# OpenShift Wildfly war file deployement using SFTP

Tags: deployment, war, sftp, openshift, wildfly

I am trying to deploy a war file in a WildFly gear through a SFTP client.

I have followed the directions described here: 
https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1088-how-to-deploy-pre-compiled-java-applications-war-and-ear-files-onto-your-openshift-gear  but can't find anything about WildFly.

More specifically I was hoping to find app-root/dependencies/wildfly/deployments but as fas as I can tell there is no such directory.

Is there something I am missing or should I only use the git way for wildfly war deployement?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to easily deploy a war file, I would suggest using rhc port-forward (as shown here in the README https://github.com/openshift-cartridges/openshift-wildfly-cartridge/blob/master/README.md) and use the web interface to deploy it.  I wrote that article and it does need to have WildFly added, I'll try to get it updated this week.  From what I can see right off, you should put your war file into ~/wildfly/standalone/deployments to deploy it via SFTP.  If you run this command find . -name "*deployed" when you ssh into your gear, you will see the ROOT.war.deployed in that directory.

Comment: Haven't checked it yet but I trust that it works, will update when I do. Thanks!

Comment: Something else that I haven't Figured out yet. What should I do after I deploy the war to wildfly/standalone/deployments ?

Comment: What do you mean? Once you put the file in there, it will create a file.war.deployed file to show it's deployed, then go visit your application.  if you want to replace the default application, rename your war file ROOT.war, if you name it something else, that is where your application will live, say you deploy myapp.war, it will live at app-domain.rhcloud.com/myapp

Comment: Everything works as described above and at your KB article. I only had to wait a bit in order to delete the filename.deployed file since, i guess, it was used by the os. Thanks again!